# Can't Install Google Play Service - Maps Component in my Xamarin Project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, nuget

I'm trying to install Google Play Services - Maps in a Xamarin Android project, it is shown in the list of Components in the PC, but when i add it to the project (even through "Add to project" in component list or trying to redownload it) it just shout out

> "Some required packages are not referenced by this project".

This is an image of the output, turns out than happend with every single component, it just re-download, show the percentage thing and then output what it is in the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ErvC.jpg

i already try:

- Delete Google Play Services - Maps from .nuget folder (no change about the problem)
- Restarting VS 2015 (the one which i'm using, include Xamarin)
- Reinstalling VS 2015 (the one which i'm using, include Xamarin)
- Change the target framework of the application (you guess it, no change)

PS: If you know where i can find windows support for this one, please show me, i know SO is better, but i wanna leave a little comment there too...

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need to use the `Component Store` when these packages exist in `NuGet`. When you try to install this package from `NuGet`, you should get a more detailed error. My best guess would be that you need to ensure you have set your `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` to the minimum for this latest stable package which is `7.0`.

Comment: Nice try but it doesn't work, thanks in any case, any other ideas about?

Comment: Please include any logs of your Nuget error in this case. Try to install the package and add the logs to your post.

Comment: I don't know how to access the nuget logs, BUT i update the info with the output i'm receiving, i try googling how to do it but my nuget install is not standalone (is part of VS2015) i'm open to suggestions, thanks in any case.